# I am not able to install Miniconda on MacOS X with Homebrew and .zsh

Tags: homebrew, zsh, miniconda

Please help, I tried to install Miniconda on Mac OS X Mojave with:

```
brew cask install miniconda
```

then I added export path to .zshrc file (Oh my Zsh):

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/miniconda3/bin"
```

But it is not being recognized:

```
zsh: command not found: conda
```

I cant find what I am doing wrong

Comment: Update: brew cask install miniconda seems to have worked.

conda -V 
conda 4.7.12

Comment: I've just tried " it brew install --cask miniconda" it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally had to do a workaround by downloading it directly:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

but I still don't understand why Homebrew is not working

Comment: As per my post: No, it didn't

Answer (score -1):

After `brew cask install miniconda`, it was installed to `/opt/miniconda3`

Comment: `brew cask install miniconda` gives: Error: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.

and, at least on ubuntu: `brew install --cask miniconda` gives:
Error: Cask 'miniconda' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

Comment: for me `brew info --cask miniconda` gave the "unavailable" error, but `brew install --cask miniconda` worked.

Comment: strangely, I tried the exact same `brew info --cask miniconda` command afterwards, and it worked this time. Not sure what happened./

Answer (score -1):

After installing miniconda using homebrew, you will need to run:

```
/opt/miniconda3/condabin/conda init zsh
```

For more info see https://discourse.brew.sh/t/why-does-brew-cask-install-miniconda-to-opt-instead-of-usr-local-caskroom/7926

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all.